# Novel where minds uploaded into computers form cliques, but a system failure leads to some deaths

Tags: story-identification, novel, mind-uploading

Thanks all, I'm going back to my youth and I'd like to re-read a novel, which I was reminded of by a recent TV show.

Fairly short, published by the traditional yellow covers. Read around mid 70's.

Story told from male perspective, uploaded minds into computer, they formed cliques and groups just as people do now but in a cyber environment. Accident happens and some friends are "lost" due to computer failure. Scenario takes place where the two main protagonists find physical comfort in each other.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Are these minds permanently uploaded (losing their bodies) or are the brains wired into the computer so they experience consciousness in the computer but can (at least theoretically) safely disconnect and leave?

Comment: Also, is this near-future or distant future?  On Earth or another planet or in space?

Comment: Permanently uploaded
Near future, Earth

I was a young guy of about 14 when I read the novel, but it's the first I can remember reading of the concept humans being able to live in cyber-land (before it was even thought of as a reality) btw I'm a cyber researcher doing my PhD in AI (swarm robotics) and this is driving me mad - it might have been the novel that interested me in the subject